# MySQL date function not accepting sub queries

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run a sub query within my TIMESTAMP function in MySQL v5.7.11.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP(SELECT NOW() AS currentDate);
```

I get an error saying

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT NOW() AS currentDate)' at line 1
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you post your full query?

Comment: try SELECT TIMESTAMP(NOW()) as currentDate;

Comment: Why is it necessary to use a second SELECT?  How does this differ from the much simpler **`SELECT NOW() AS \`whatever\``**  Why does the return from the `NOW()` function (a DATETIME datatype) need to be an argument to the `TIMESTAMP` function... which returns a DATETIME?  I'm confused as to why this obfuscation isn't eschewed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add extra pair of brackets inside your subquery.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP((SELECT NOW() AS currentDate));
```